# DVD doesnt Autoplay!

Tags: 15.10, dvd, autoplay

I just a bought an educational DVD but it doesn't autoplay rather opens up the DVD files maybe because of the autorun.exe which cannot run in ubuntu. How do I play the DVD and watch the videos in it?Help PLease! 
                    Thank You!

Comment: More detail would likely result in useful answers. What files do you see on the DVD?

Comment: Autorun.exe, Autorun.inf and a Autoplay folder within which folders named VIdeo,Audio,Plugins,Flash ,Scripts etc.

Comment: Open the Video Folder and you should be able to play the videos with the default player in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to install *Wine* and execute the program with it. *Wine* is a program that let you run Microsoft Windows application on Linux (in few words).

To install *Wine* you can use the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

Installation will take a bit, because has to download a lot of packages. If you get some dependencies error you can run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

which should solve package dependencies errors.

After installation you can double-click on Autorun.exe and launch the DVD application.

I've got same problem with a DVD found in a school book and I've solved it in this way.